# How to connect puckel/docker-airflow to local windows SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, airflow, python-3.7, pyodbc

So, I'm trying to connect to my local instance of SQL Server on windows from airflow dag.

The major error is that pyodbc or pymmssql libraries are not installed even after explicitly mentioning them in the docker file. I've followed the instructions from [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)  under Debian 9 and [Medium](https://medium.com/analytics-and-data/setting-up-airflow-on-azure-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-8c06784a7e2b) as the image is built on it.

All the tasks in dag run fine except for the one I am trying to connect to the SQL Server with the error:

> [2020-04-03 22:23:42,303] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - No module
>   named 'pyodbc'

If I try pip install from the airflow container it is not installing in the `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and not able to import in the dag.

I have also included requirements.txt in the volume but had no luck.

Did anyone had a successful connection in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by building the airflow image form the Dockerfile. while building you need to add few dependencies.

sqlalchemy:

```
&& pip3 uninstall SQLAlchemy \
&& pip3 install SQLAlchemy==1.3.15 \
```

pyodbc:

```
&& apt-get install python3-dev -y\
&& apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y\
&& pip3 install pyodbc \
```

Another long way would be to change the USER as root and build the image and ap-get install from the container and change change the USER back to airflow but this is more efficient if you know what you are installing.